# Ubuntu 16.04 Mouse Jumps to trash icon all the time.

Tags: touchpad, dell, trash

When using the track pad on my Dell laptop the mouse always seems to jump to the trash icon in the left corner of the screen. I have also had the same experience when using 16.10. What is going on?